# Photo library as subview of another view (Under segmented control.)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a segment controller on one of my views and now on the 0th index of segment controller I want to add `UIImagePickerController` (for showing Albums view to user) by adding as sub view and not by `ModalViewController`.

The Image Picker controller appears but it does not navigate to show images inside.. it just shows a blank table view when I select the row showing the image count.

So my question is whether this can be achieved or I will have to present it as modal view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I used to zoom the imagePicker, which involved adding its view to the Application Delegate's window - not quite the same, but at least it shows that you don't have to present it using ModalViewController, and I'm sure it could easily be adapted -

```
-(void)presentCameraWithDelegate:(id)theDelegate {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self setImagePickerController:imagePicker];

    imagePicker.delegate = theDelegate;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;


    UIView *controllerView = imagePickerController.view;

    controllerView.alpha = 0.0;
    controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:controllerView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     controllerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                     controllerView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil
     ];

    [imagePicker release];

}
```

Sorry about all the superfluous code! Hope it helps.

Comment: Although this might achieve OP's desired effect, it might not be a good idea to actually do this. Adding the view of another view controller as a subview of another view is generally a bad idea, and is not the way view management should work in iOS. OP's call, though.

Comment: Appreciate your concern here, and wouldn't use this method with normal view controllers - but I couldn't think of another way to get the ImagePicker's view to use in the way I wanted, rather than having my hand forced by PresentModalViewController.

Comment: adding photo library as a subview is not possible the navigation to internal structure of the library is not supported. I guess we are left with two options , either to create a custom library reader or just to present as modal view controller.